# PHP adds escape back slashes. How to stop this

Tags: php, escaping, magic-quotes-gpc

Background: I am not a php programmer, and I only know enough to get the web service parts of my iOS apps working.

I am finding that my php is adding backslashes to my text, when I don't want it to. For example if I set up some variables like this:

```
$directory = "directory/";
$file = "file.jpg"
```

then I output via a JSON array back to my device:

```
$directory . $file
```

and I get

```
"directory\/file.jpg"
```

I have run get_magic_quotes_gpc with in my php and it reports that magic quotes is turned off. I do this this way:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
//then I send something back in the JSON array to let me know that get_magic_quotes_gpc is on
}
```

I have tried to use stripslashes() (on either the original variables or the output) and nothing changes.

So how do I stop it from doing this? As it means that I can't tell my php to delete files in specific directories.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you care? In JSON strings ``\/`` and ``/`` are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't realise that this was only happening in JSON, I thought it represented what was really happening in the php.

I thought this was a symptom of an issue I was having elsewhere, but it turns out that I had been barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you encode your elements do it as so:

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`should prevent the addition of unwanted slashes.

Comment: simple and straight to the point, this should be the accepted anwser; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really want to do this, then set [the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).

```
json_encode ( $value, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
```

But the slashes do no harm and provide protection against `</script>` being injected into a `<script>` element when you inject your JSON into a JavaScript program.

Comment: thank for the reply. I actually don't need the JSON reply (at least not for this), I am just using it to see what is going on (as my files are not getting found by the php).

Perhaps my problem is elsewhere then.